# How to connect VSTS account to Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, office365, azure-active-directory

I'm following the article [Connect VSTS account to Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/connect-account-to-aad), but I'm not able to make it running.

My current status is:

**VSTS**
account: test
owner: lukas@test.com (MS Account)

**Azure**
owner: lukas@test.com (Office 365 account)
Azure Active Directory: Office 365
Subscription: Pay-as-you-go

When I sign in to **portal.azure.com** by using **Office 365 account**, and navigate to **Team services accounts**, there is just message `Nothing to display`.

But if I sign in to **portal.azure.com** by using **MS account**, and navigate to **Team services accounts**, I see my VSTS account **test**. Then I'm able to link it to existing subscription and connect to to AAD, but **it's not** Office 365 AAD

Can anybody tell me what to do (step by step) and which account (Office 365 / MS) should I use?

Comment: Do you check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/faq-azure-access#ChangeMSA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be done through the Azure portal. If you have the same problem, just contact **MS Support** and they will help you to fix it.